# Invalid block tag on line 8: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django

l'm  a fresh user in Django and l am learning through Youtube videos. l did everything same but l got this block tag error.
Here is my template name base.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

</body>
```

Another template name home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content % }

<h1>Hello , Welcome Home</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py content :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    context ={}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request , template , context)
```

I have tried several times but still i could not find where the errors are. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% block content % }
```

should be

```
{% block content %}
```

No space between % and }.